# Checking if a C++ header includes standard container

Tags: c++

I am writing some test cases and I want to write a test case which can determine at run time if any stl containers are used in a C++ header file.

Is there any standard macro which are included when vector, list, map etc. etc. header files are included?

I am using Gnu C++ Compiler.

Comment: There certainly are no standard macros that do this. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I am evaluating few programs and want to make sure that no one used standard container. I am writing to C++ code to check same.

Comment: "want to make sure that no one used standard container", yes, but why? Anyway, grep is your friend.

Comment: Yes, seems like grep would be the best way out here. Thanks.

Comment: This is a long shot but does is_class work (i.e. compile) if the argument is not recognised at the point of compilation? I'm thinking in terms of this problem being equivalent to checking if a container is known to the compiler as an incomplete type.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - Because the assignment which I am evaluating had this restriction.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Seems like is_class would do the required thing. I will give a try.

Comment: @Bath No idea - but there are lots of things in the standard library that are not classes.

Comment: Yes, but I will be able to detect many using is_class.

Comment: Is your restriction on using the standard library at all or just on declaring things like vector<sometype>?

Comment: Restriction was "not to use standard containers.. Ones mentioned here [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/] "

Comment: So you need to detect things like void f( vector<sometype> s ); Well, I still think the best bet is grepping for the standard library headers, who's names are reserved.

Comment: You might have more luck if you reword your question to express your actual intent (ie "how can I prevent my students from using STL containers in their assignments")

Comment: @meagar - Can you suggest edit? I can edit but as you suggested so I think it would be better if system logs it too. :)

Comment: @MayankJain No, it's just a suggestion. If you want to update your question, feel free to do so.

Comment: There is no standard macro for this purpose.  Personally, I'd just do it in your build script using (as alredy suggested) grep.   Before compiling each file, capture its preprocessor output (`gcc -E`), search that output for the name of standard containers (`vector`, etc) and fail the build if they are found.   Only thing to watch is that it will also detect cases where someone has created their own container (outside namespace std) with the same name.